# ubuntu 11.10, ROS electric and TiXmlElement ( tinyxml ) compiling error

Tags: ros, tinyxml, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_controllers/control_toolbox/lib/libcontrol_toolbox.so: undefined reference to TiXmlElement::Attribute(char const*) const' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

I have following compilation error and don't have any idea how to solve it. I think it might be linked to this following problem:
http://answers.ros.org/questions/2296/revisions/
But still quite don't know how to solve this.

EDIT:
After doing fresh install of ROS to ubuntu I get this error msg:

`Failed to find stack for package [control_toolbox] Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [control_toolbox]:Cannot locate installation of package control_toolbox: [rospack] couldn't find package [control_toolbox].`

What would be the correct way to fix this? I think last time I used apt-get to instal necessary library.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12122/ubuntu-11.10,-ros-electric-and-tixmlelement-(-tinyxml-)-compiling-error/) by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Check if the following problem helps.
http://answers.ros.org/question/2593/error-while-loading-shared-libraries

Thanks,
Karthik

---

**Updated**

Use the following to checkout the control_toolbox into your ros_workspace

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_controllers/branches/pr2_controllers-1.4/control_toolbox wg-ros-pkg/pr2_controllers/control_toolbox
```

You have to compile this package using

```
rosmake control_toolbox
```

I hope you have a ros_workspace in place so that ros path fetches downloaded package without any issues. If not pls go through http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-30**:
When an answer is correct please mark it as so using the checkbox.  I've done so for you.

**Comment by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on 2011-11-29**:
Thank you this helped. I have to assume there was something wrong with my initial control_toolbox install.